Creating worksheets with answers at the end
Several years ago, I asked two questions trying to generate an automated way to make student worksheets with answer keys (Writing enumitem's to a file and
How do I reference the current enumerant label without having to tag each one by hand).  Recently, the solution I was using broke which had me reviewing the comments and answers from those questions.  One of the comments spoke about using the ref value from enumitem.  Based on this, I wrote the MWE included below which seems to work and be significantly simpler than other solutions I have tried.
I would like to automatically generate the appropriate reference (see DESIRED in the MWE).
Related question:  `enumdepth` and `ifthenelse`
EDIT: Perhaps the solution involves the ideas here (but it is beyond me): (see Automatically switch between \theenumi, \theenumii, and \theenumiii based on \@enumdepth )
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newwrite\answerkeyfile
\newcounter{answercount}
\setcounter{answercount}{0}
\immediate\openout\answerkeyfile=\jobname.keys

\newcommand{\answerkey}[1]{\label{ans:\theanswercount}%
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\string\ref{ans:\theanswercount}\ }%
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{ }%
  \stepcounter{answercount}%
}

\newcommand{\inputAnswers}{%
     \immediate\closeout\answerkeyfile%
     \input{\jobname.keys}%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
    \immediate\closeout\answerkeyfile%
}

\begin{document}

% DESIRED: ... ref={\parent\arabic*} ...
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*}, ref={\arabic*}]
\item Level 1. \answerkey{Answer 1}

% DESIRED: ... ref={\parent\alph*} ....
  \begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*}, ref={\theenumi\alph*}]
  \item Level 2a. \answerkey{Answer 2a}

  \item Level 2b. \answerkey{Answer 2b}

% DESIRED: ... ref={\parent\roman*} ...
  \begin{enumerate}[label={\roman*}, ref={\theenumii\roman*}]
      \item Level 3. \answerkey{Answer 3}

        \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\inputAnswers

\end{document}


If I understand your question correctly, the following adaptation of this answer to the question you linked to should do the trick:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newwrite\answerkeyfile
\newcounter{answercount}
\setcounter{answercount}{0}
\immediate\openout\answerkeyfile=\jobname.keys

\newcommand{\answerkey}[1]{\label{ans:\theanswercount}%
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\string\ref{ans:\theanswercount}\ }%
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  \immediate\write\answerkeyfile{ }%
  \stepcounter{answercount}%
}

\newcommand{\inputAnswers}{%
     \immediate\closeout\answerkeyfile%
     \input{\jobname.keys}%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
    \immediate\closeout\answerkeyfile%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_new:Npn \parent
  {
    \int_compare:nNnT { \@listdepth } > { 1 }
      {
        \use:c
          {
            theenum
            \int_to_roman:n
              { 
                \int_eval:n { \@listdepth - 1 }
              }
          }
      }
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% DESIRED: ... ref={\parent\arabic*} ...
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*}, ref={\parent\arabic*}]
\item Level 1. \answerkey{Answer 1}

% DESIRED: ... ref={\parent\alph*} ....
  \begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*}, ref={\parent\alph*}]
  \item Level 2a. \answerkey{Answer 2a}

  \item Level 2b. \answerkey{Answer 2b}

% DESIRED: ... ref={\parent\roman*} ...
  \begin{enumerate}[label={\roman*}, ref={\parent\roman*}]
      \item Level 3. \answerkey{Answer 3}

        \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\inputAnswers

\end{document}

Output:


I just compiled your answer and it looks to be exactly what I need.  I will put it into the actual environment and try it, but I have every expectation that this is perfect.  Thank you very much.

I don't know what your workflow is like, but maybe an approach with .dtx files would be worth looking into? As a basic example:
% File: root.dtx

% 
% default:   code that should be considered part of both \jobname.questions.tex and \jobname.solutions.tex
% questions: code that should only be included in \jobname.questions.tex
% solutions: code that should only be included in \jobname.solutions.tex
%

%<*driver>
\input docstrip.tex
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{
    \file{\jobname.questions.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{default,questions}}
    \file{\jobname.solutions.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{default,solutions}}
}
\endbatchfile
%</driver>
%<*default>
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{default}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%<*questions>
    \chead{Worksheet 1}
%</questions>
%<*solutions>
    \chead{Solutions to Worksheet 1}
%</solutions>
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{default}

\section{Answers with Questions}

\begin{enumerate}
\item What is the capital of France?
%<*solutions>
\fbox{Paris.}
%</solutions>
\end{enumerate}

\section{Answers only}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
%<*questions>
What is the capital of France?
%</questions>
%<*solutions>
Paris.
%</solutions>
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
%</default>

You can compile this with e.g. the following commands:
latex root.dtx && pdflatex root.solutions.tex && pdflatex root.questions.tex

This will get you two PDFs:
root.questions.pdf:

root.solutions.pdf:

If you wanted to include the answer key as an addendum, you could make sure you compile root.solutions.tex before you compile root.questions.tex and then include root.solutions.pdf at the end of root.questions.tex. But that's just one possible approach. A workflow with DTX files can be very complex, versatile, and powerful.
For more info on the DTX format, I'd recommend taking a look at the files here (starting with the README and PDFs): https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/dtxgallery

This suggestion is very useful, but in answer to your initial question -- yes, I am burdened by legacy.  I have many worksheets, quizzes, and exams that use the existing \answerkey mechanism.  So the optimal solution for my question is something that shows me how to write \parent in the MWE.  This would be nearly a drop in replacement in my existing code base.

@ChristopherDonham Ah, fair enough. I added a separate answer to your question that aims to be more in line with what I understand you're looking for. Hope it helps! :)

If what you want is to maintain the structure of the environment in which you execute the responses and their output, I think you can use the new enumext package that is designed for this task. This is an example adapted from the package documentation:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}%
\usepackage[osf]{libertinus}
\usepackage{enumext}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumext}[mode-box,save-ans=simplews,labelsep=10pt,columns=2,nosep,save-ref=true]
  \item Factor $x^{2}-2x+1$ \anskey{$\left(x-1\right)^{2}$}
  \item Factor $3x+3y+3z$ \anskey{$3(x+y+z)$}
  \item True False
    \begin{enumext}[nosep]
      \item $\alpha > \delta$ \anskey{False}
      \item \LaTeX2e\ is cool? \anskey{Very True!}
    \end{enumext}
  \item Related to Linux
    \begin{enumext}[nosep]
      \item You use linux? \anskey{Yes}
      \item Usually uses the package manager? \anskey{Yes, \texttt{dnf}}
      \item Rate the following package and class
        \begin{enumext}[nosep]
          \item \texttt{xsim-exam} \anskey{doesn't exist for now :(}
          \item \texttt{xsim} \anskey{very good}
          \item \texttt{exsheets} \anskey{obsolete}
        \end{enumext}
    \end{enumext}
\end{enumext}

The answer to \ref{simplews:1} is \getkeyans{simplews:1} and the answer
to \ref{simplews:3} is \getkeyans{simplews:3}.

\printkeyans[columns=2]{simplews}
\end{document}


The answers and structure are stored in memory and you can print them at the end of the document without any problems.
